# Schema compare fails, SQL Server 2008 R2 & VS2010 Premium with time out expired error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, schema, compare

I have a VS2010 DB Project migrated form VS2008 and a couple of schema comparisons created.

I get the following error:

`Error 1 An error was received from SQL Server while attempting to reverse engineer elements of type Microsoft.Data.Schema.Sql.SchemaModel.ISqlUser: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.`

`Error 2 ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.`

I am using VS2010 Premium and SQL Server 20008 R2 on my dev machine.
My database is hosted on local instance of SQL server.
When I use the same schema comparision with a remote server and use the `sa` login it works. On my dev machine, I tried with `sa` login as well. but no luck!

Has anyone encountered such an issue and was able to resolve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well cracked it! (not sure if that is the solution, at least it now works for me)

The local databases I was using for schema comparison were restored from backups of production databases. The users in the databases will loose their SID (probably) with the ones mapped on the production server.

I simply deleted the database users and recreated them and the schema comparison started working again.